# There are $52$ cards in a deck. Find the probability that the $3$ cards add up to $7$.

Tags: probability

(Note:  Aces are considered a high card, not $1$)

Case 1:  You deal $3$ cards simultaneously, all sets of three cards equally likely.

Case 2:  You deal a card, note the draw, replace it and shuffle and pack, and follow the process $3$ times in all.

a) What is |Omega| or the size of the sample space of all outcomes?

b) Find the probability that the $3$ cards add up to $7$.

*Please show details. I have tried several different ways. I do feel confident that Case $1$ sample space as $52$C$3$ and Case $2$ sample space as $52$x$52$x$52$. I am having trouble with the numerator. Help please. Thank you*

Comment: Hint: It seems like the only ways to get three cards that sum to seven would be {1, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 3}, or {2, 2, 3}.

Comment: if aces do not count as 1, then the only combination of 3 cards is 2,2,3

Comment: Your "denominators" are indeed right. It should not be difficult to count the number of $2,2,3$ hands both in the no replacement case and in the replacement case. The two procedures are quite different.

Comment: I was thinking of the following for the only set in question 2,2,3:  Case#1 [(4C2)(4C1)]/(52C3) and Case#2 [(4C1)(4C1))(4C1)]/[(52)(52)(52)], but not so sure.

Answer (score 2):

To do it in a CAS, we can use bivariate ordinary and exponential generating functions.

#### Case 1b:

\begin{align*}
  G_1(x,y) &= \left(\left(1+x y^A\right) \, \left(1+x y^K\right) \left(1+x y^Q\right) \left(1+x y^J\right)\prod_{i=1}^9 \left(1+x y^i\right)\right)^4
\end{align*}
$[x^3 y^7]G_1(x,y)$ is the required number of ways of choosing the cards without replacement and the probability is $\dfrac{24}{\binom{52}{3}}$

#### Case 2b:

\begin{align*}
  G_2(x,y) &= \exp\left(4x\left(y^A+y^K+y^Q+y^J+\sum_{i=2}^9 y^i\right)\right)
\end{align*}
$[x^3 y^7]G_2(x,y) \times 3!$ is the required number of ways of choosing the cards with replacement and the probability is $\dfrac{192}{52^3}$

$x$ keeps track of the number of cards chosen and $y$ keeps track of the sum.

Comment: I originally had considered 3!/2! s.t. [(4x4x4)(3!/2!)]/(52x52x52), but started to doubt having to include the arrangement of {2,2,3} when we are considering a sum.  Do you mind explaining :).  Thank you.

Comment: Referring to case 2.  I was good on the other.

Comment: Possible arrangements are {(2,2,3), (2,3,2), (3,2,2)}, and also there are 4 possible suits in each position since replacement is allowed. Hence, $3\times 4^3 = 192$

Comment: But I was wondering if the sum of 2,2,3=7, no matter the arrangement, do we have to factor in the arrangement anyhow?  Is it due to the fact of doing it "with replacement?" I just don't see it clearly.  Help :)

Comment: Yes, with replacement, e.g. $\left(2\clubsuit, 2\diamondsuit, 3\clubsuit\right)$ have a probability of $\frac{1}{52}\cdot \frac{1}{52}\cdot \frac{1}{52}$ and adding up with arrangement gives $\frac{6}{52^3}$. But when doing without replacement, the probability is $\frac{1}{52}\cdot \frac{1}{51}\cdot \frac{1}{50}$, and adding all the arrangements give $\frac{6}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50}$, which is same as $\frac{1}{\binom{52}{3}}$

Answer (score 1):

### Case 1:

- You select three of fifty-two cards without repetition. There are $^{52}{\rm C}_{3}$ ways to do this. (Order of draw is not important for the probability measure.)
- Arranging the cards from lowest to highest, the faces which add up to seven are: $\{1,1,5\}, \{1,2,4\}, \{1,3,3\}, \{2,2,3\}$. There are $4^3$ ways to select suits for three distinct faces, and there are $4\cdot{^{4}{\rm C}_{2}}$ ways to select suits for each of the remaining three groups (the "pairs").

  - If Aces are not one, we only need count $\{2,2,3\}$

### Case 2:

- You select three of thirteen faces with repetition allowed. There are $13^3$ ways to do this.   (We can ignore the suits; but order of draw is important for the probability measure.)
- Arranging the cards from lowest to highest, the faces which add up to seven are: $\{1,1,5\}, \{1,2,4\}, \{1,3,3\}, \{2,2,3\}$. However there are $3$ ways to arrange each of the three "pairs", and $3!$ ways to arrange the singleton hand.

  - If Aces are not one, we only need count $\{2,2,3\}$

Comment: On case 1:  I came up with [(4C2)(4C1)]/(52C3) which I believe is what you have indicated as well.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed @user217189

Comment: On case 2 I was thinking (4x4x4)/(52x52x52), but you have indicated 13x13x13 ways to do this and indicated arrangements as well, why is this